# Computing basis from projector

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an idempotent matrix $P$, is there any way to "extract" a basis of the subspace that $P$ projects onto?

Comment: Use the eigenvectors of the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$.

Comment: You can note that the subspace that $P$ projects onto is the complement of the kernel of $P$.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Can't see how it helps compute the basis

Comment: @EmilioNovati $P$ is not uniquely determined by its kernel (unless it's an orthogonal projection).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: You are right!  I was thinking to orthogonal....

Answer (score 1):

The subspace that $P$ projects onto is its image, so it suffices to get a basis for the image (column space) of $P$.

The traditional method is as follows: row-reduce, and note which columns become "pivot columns" (columns containing a row's leading $1$).  The columns of $P$ that become pivot columns form a basis of the image of $P$.

Comment: Let's take apart that statement *"I thought, some transformation like $P=FI_r F^{−1}$ would help"*.  How do you expect it to help?  Note that finding such an $F$ amounts precisely to finding all eigenvectors of $P$, since the columns of $F$ **are** the eigenvectors of $P$.

Comment: The quickest method is to look at the columns of $P$ and select a maximal linearly independent set.  The row-reduction method does this systematically.

Comment: You mean only non-zero columns?

Comment: A set containing a zero column necessarily fails to be linearly independent.  So yes, you should only be looking for collections of non-zero columns.